In my Blazor server side app with windows authentication I want to block all users except the defined users, from passing the login page
I am using windows authentication in my blazor serve side app but currently all the users in our company that enter their domain usernames and passwords can enter the page. What I want is very simple:
I want to define a username list (user1,user2,user3) and let in only these users to my page.  Currently I can let in just some users to some pages with following code, but in this case I have to define the authorization code in all my razor pages.
Can I do it more simple with a central configuration?
my Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
     options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificUsers", policy =>
     policy.RequireUserName("user1", "user2", "user3"));
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
}

on each razor page
<AuthorizeView Roles="user1,user2,user3">
 <Authorized>
     <p>Welcome, user1, user2, or user3!</p>
 </Authorized>
 <NotAuthorized>
 <p>Access denied. You are not authorized to view this content.</p>
</NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

